# How should I add my period by period constraint in lagrangian?

Tags: optimization, consumption, lagrangian, financial-constraints

This question just suddenly comes to my mind, and I'm not sure what i'm thinking is correct:
suppose I want to maximize my cumulative expected utility $E\left[ \sum_{t=0}^{T}\beta^tU(c_t) \right]$ by choosing $\alpha_{t+1}$, and $\theta_{t+1}$, which are the dollar amount i invest in bonds and stock respectively.
I have periods by periods budget constraint which is:
$$w_t-c_t=\alpha_{t+1}B(t)+\theta_{t+1}S(t)$$
$$w_{t+1}=\alpha_{t+1}B(t+1)+\theta_{t+1}(S(t+1)+D(t+1))$$

My question is: if i write lagrangian, should I add the constraints into $\beta^t$ like: $$E\left[ \sum_{t=0}^{T}\beta^t\left(  U(c_t)+\lambda_t\text{constraint1}+\gamma_t\text{constraint2} \right) \right]$$
or should I add the constraints outside $\beta^t$ but inside the summation since it is still period by period:
$$E\left[ \sum_{t=0}^{T}\left(\beta^t  U(c_t)+\lambda_t\text{constraint1}+\gamma_t\text{constraint2}\right)  \right]$$

I personally think it is the first one, because the period by period budget constraints should also be discounted towards t=0 dollar amount, and also if I do not add the constraints in lagrangian way, but simply replace the $c_t$ inside the utility function, it is the same as the first case.

What do you think? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it does not really matter.

The values of $\lambda_t$ and $\gamma_t$ that you will get in the first setting will simply be the values of $\lambda_t$ and $\gamma_t$ in the second approach multiplied by $\beta^t$.

Note that you can write the first Lagrangian as:
$$
E\left[\sum_{t = 0}^T \left(\beta^t U(c_t) + \beta^t \lambda_t \text{ constraint 1} + \beta^t \gamma_t \text{ constraint 2}\right)\right].
$$
So redefining $\tilde \lambda_t = \beta^t \lambda_t$ and $\tilde \gamma_t = \beta^t \gamma_t$, we get:

$$
E\left[\sum_{t = 0}^T \left(\beta^t U(c_t) + \tilde \lambda_t \text{ constraint 1} + \tilde \gamma_t \text{ constraint 2}\right)\right].
$$
which is in the form of the second Lagrangian.

Of course, the interpreation of the the Lagrange multipliers will differ somewhat: $\lambda_t$ and $\gamma_t$ are the multipliers evaluated at time $t$ while $\tilde \lambda_t$ and $\tilde \gamma_t$ are the values evaluated at time $0$.

The issue is somewhat equivalent to the question of using the present versus current value hamiltonian for continuous time dynamics.