The two equivalent ways to write the Lagrangian (infinite-horizon planning problem)?
My friend and I were studying a simple infinite-horizon planning model today, and we encountered some interesting things when we solved it with the Lagrangian. Suppose we have a Ramsey model:
$$
\max_{c_t, k_{t+1}} \sum^{\infty}_{t=0} \beta^t u(c_t), \\
s.t. c_t + k_{t+1} = f(k_t) - (1-\delta)k_t
$$
To solve it, my friend wrote the Lagrangian like this. (1)
$$
L_t = \beta^t \left[ u(c_t) + \lambda_t ( f(k_t) - (1-\delta)k_t - c_t - k_{t+1}) \right ]
$$
The FOCs:
$$
(c_t): u'(c_t) = \lambda_t, \\
(k_{t+1}): \lambda_t = \beta \lambda_{t+1} [ f'(k_{t+1}) - (1-\delta) ]
$$
and envelope
$$
u'(c_{t+1}) = \lambda_{t+1}
$$
However, I wrote the Lagrangian like this. (2)
$$
L_t = \beta^t u(c_t) + \lambda_t ( f(k_t) - (1-\delta)k_t - c_t - k_{t+1})
$$
The FOCs:
$$
(c_t): \beta^t u'(c_t) = \lambda_t, \\
(k_{t+1}): \lambda_t = \lambda_{t+1} [f'(k_{t+1}) - (1-\delta)]
$$
and envelope
$$
u'(c_{t+1}) = \beta^{t+1} \lambda_{t+1}
$$
Both of these methods yield the same Euler equation.
$$
\frac{u'(c_t)}{u'(c_{t+1})} = \beta [ f'(k_{t+1}) - (1-\delta) ]
$$
Some textbooks use first writing, while others use second.
My question is: Although these 2 ways give you the same Euler equation, are there any reasons why one of them is the correct way to formulate the problem compared to the other?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/57813/how-should-i-add-my-period-by-period-constraint-in-lagrangian
